# Error missing $ and extra }

Tags: amsmath, text

I typed the following code :

```
\subsubsection{x....x}
x..................x \textit{a} and  \textit{a^{\dagger}} :
```

This gives me the error missing $ inserted or extra }. Please tell me how to correct this error.

Comment: `a^{\dagger}` should be between dollar signs as it is a math expression: `$a^{\dagger}$`

Comment: `^`must be used in math mode. Just write `$a$ and $a^{\dagger}$`.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `text $a$ and $a^{\dagger}$`?

Answer (score 1):

Avoid the error by :

```
\subsubsection{Lx.....x}
x...........x \textit{a} and 
\begin{math}
\mathit{a^\dagger} :
\end{math}
```

the dagger is a math symbol and hence should be included in math environment. To get italics on a math symbol use \mathit{} instead of \textit{}.